# Most occurred letter in a string using php function

Tags: php, string

i have string `AABBBCCCDABBAACBB` , in this i need to find the most occurrence of Character , how can i find this??

in above string it should return 7 ad B comes 7 times i.e max.

```
$str = "AABBBCCCABB";
$strArray = count_chars($str,1);

foreach ($strArray as $key=>$value)
{
    echo "The character <b>'".chr($key)."'</b> was found $value time(s)<br>";
    //$highest=chr($key);
    if(isset($highest) && $highest>chr($key))
    {
        $highest=chr($key);
    }
}
echo "<br/><br/>Highest value is ::".$highest;
```

above code i tried,

i tried but functionality is not perfect , which function of `php` i should use?

Comment: "Functionality is not perfect" is a _really_ poor description of a problem. Please try to provide at least a _little_ bit more information about _how_ the code doesn't do what you want. (That said, I see some obvious bugs in your code, so just "does not return the correct value" would've been an adequate description in this particular case.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a loop for this. Use [`array_search()`](http://php.net/array_search) to find the key of the most repeated value, and use [`chr()`](http://php.net/chr) on it:

```
$str = "AABBBCCCDABBAACBB";
$strArray = count_chars($str,1);
echo chr(array_search(max($strArray), $strArray));
```

Output:

```
B
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/59873)

Comment: ...Accepted as an answer, i marked one more by mistake so this mark was gone

Answer (score 1):

```
$string="AABBBCCCABB";
foreach (str_split($string) as $s){
    if (isset($counts[$s])) continue;
    $counts[$s]=substr_count($string, $s);
    echo "The character <b>'" . $s . "'</b> was found ".$counts[$s]." time(s)<br>";
}
$maxs=array_keys($counts, max($counts));
echo "Highest value is ::'".$maxs[0];
```

Comment: Please don't shout at people who are helping.

Comment: not shouting it is just by mistake caps on .... i was trying his code ...@popnoodles thnx buddy

Comment: @NigelAngel i think better if u try to help by giving answer instead of creating misunderstandings!!

Answer (score 0):

Solution for your code by your way:

```
$str = "AABBBCCCABB";
$strArray = count_chars($str,1);
$highest = $str[0];
$times = 0;

foreach ($strArray as $key=>$value){
    echo "The character <b>'".chr($key)."'</b> was found $value time(s)<br>";
    //$highest=chr($key);
    if($times < $value)
    {
        $times = $value;
        $highest=chr($key);
    }

}

  echo "<br/><br/>Highest value is ::".$highest;
```

But answer of Alma Do is better to use.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `max()` function:

```
$str = "AABBBCCCABB";
$strArray = count_chars($str,1);
$highest = max($strArray);
foreach ($strArray as $key=>$value) {
  echo "The character <b>'" . chr($key) . "'</b> was found $value time(s)<br>";
}
echo "<br/><br/>Highest value is ::" . $highest;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution, hope this helps you to solve.

```
$string  =  "AABBBCCCABB";
$letters = array_count_values(str_split($string));
$val = array_search(max($letters), $letters);
echo $val;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
echo maxCountChar("AABBBCCCDABBAACBB");

function maxCountChar($string){
    foreach (str_split($string) as $s){
        $counts[$s]=substr_count($string, $s);
    }
    $maxs=array_keys($counts, max($counts));
    $num = substr_count($string, $maxs[0]);
    return "The character <b>$maxs[0]</b> was found <b>$num</b> times";
}
```

**Output**

```
The character B was found 7 times
```